# Excel formula - Count number of rows containing 2 string values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Given the input table shown above, I am looking to count how many times Gilles and Qiao play together. For that I am looking to find all rows where Player1, Player 2 or Player 3 is "Gilles" AND Player1, Player2 or Player 3 is "Qiao"

I used following formula with COUNTIFS which should allow to test multiple criteria (AND Logic) but result is always 0 when using multiple columns.

```
=COUNTIFS(Tableau5[#All],"Qiao",Tableau5[#All],"Gilles")
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am struggling to get it to work.

| Player1 | Player2 | Player3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gilles | Patrick | Hugo |
| Qiao | Hugo | Gilles |
| Pedro | Qiao | Gilles |
| Gilles | Hugo | Patrick |
| Pedro | Patrick | Hugo |
| Qiao | Hugo | Patrick |
| Pedro | Qiao | Gilles |
| Gilles | Hugo | Qiao |
| Pedro | Patrick | Hugo |
| Gilles | Qiao | Patrick |

Comment: Please use **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** so that community members can copy the data to post solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT((A2:C11="Gilles")+(A2:C11="Qiao"),{1;1;1})=2))
```

---

Data:

| Player1 | Player2 | Player3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gilles | Patrick | Hugo |
| Qiao | Hugo | Gilles |
| Pedro | Qiao | Gilles |
| Gilles | Hugo | Patrick |
| Pedro | Patrick | Hugo |
| Qiao | Hugo | Patrick |
| Pedro | Qiao | Gilles |
| Gilles | Hugo | Qiao |
| Pedro | Patrick | Hugo |
| Gilles | Qiao | Patrick |

Comment: I implemented this solution it worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
=SUM(BYROW(A2:C11,LAMBDA(z,OR(z=E2)*OR(z=E3))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This formula was working but I had some issues generating the formula from Aspose.Cells with z variable beeing renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> with <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd>. Note that I have assumed you have the criteria delimited with a <kbd>+</kbd> if not then the answer would be same as **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir's.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B15</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Tableau5,TEXTSPLIT(A15," + ")))),
SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Tableau5[#Headers]),,,0))>1))
```

---

You don't need a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions it can solved using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>, still here is an alternative

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(BYROW((Tableau5=E2)+(F2=Tableau5),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)>1))))
```

---

If the criteria is not delimited and are places in two adjacent cells then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Tableau5,E2:F2))),
SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Tableau5[#Headers]),,,0))>1))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

### Count the Occurrences of Two Matching Strings Per Row

[image]

```
=LET(data,Tableau5,Players,{"Qiao","Gilles"},
    SUM(--BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,COUNT(XMATCH(Players,r))>1))))
```

```
=LET(data,Tableau5,Players,E2:E3,
    SUM(--BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,COUNT(XMATCH(Players,r))>1))))
```